# Solution of $ay''+by'+cy=0$ with positive constants $a,b,c$ satisfies $y(x)\to0$ as $x\to\infty$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> Given that $a, b, c$ are positive constants and $y(x)$ is a solution to the differential equation $ay''+by'+cy=0$, show that $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} y(x) = 0$.

I've been able to determine that the general solution $y(x)=c_1e^{r_1x} + c_2e^{r_2x}$ should have $r_1$ and $r_2$ be negative (I found this by playing around with the numbers in GeoGebra). As for the proper solution though, I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characteristic equation is
$$az^2+bz+c=0.$$
Assuming real roots, they must be negative, otherwise the expression would be positive.

Assuming complex conjugate roots, their real part is $-b/2a$, a negative number.

In all cases, the solution decays exponentially to $0$.